# How can I update only specific MySQL database table columns in Laravel 7 Controller?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I would like to update some specific columns in MySQL table that holds data for a Project. The table called "projects" has many columns but I would like a user to only update few columns. I have written some code for it but when the user submits the form the data is not updated in the table. I'm quite new to Laravel. Kindly help.

NB: I have put "start_date" column to be a String but I can change it later. For now I just want the data to be updated in my database.

In my Controller:

```
/**
     * Show the form for editing the specified Project.
     *
     */
    public function edit(Project $project, $id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
        
        return view('client_panel.projects.edit',compact('project'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified Project in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'                  => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description'           => 'required|string|max:255',
            'start_date'            => 'required|date',
            'start_time'            => 'required|string|max:10',
        ]);
  
        $project->update($request->all());
  
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'You have successfully updated your Job Card');
    }

}
```

My Editing Form in Blade View:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('client-jobcard.update',$project->id) }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PATCH')
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <label for="name">{{ __('Job Card Name') }}</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ $project->name }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <label for="description">{{ __('Job Card Description') }}</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                <textarea class="form-control{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="description" rows="4" style="height: 150px;" name="description" required autofocus>{{ $project->description }}</textarea>
                                @if ($errors->has('description'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="start_date">Start Date</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date"  name="start_date" value="{{ $project->start_date }}" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="submission_date">Start Time</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start_time"  name="start_time" value="{{ $project->start_time }}" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Submit') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>   
                    </form>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('client-jobcard/create', 'ProjectController@create')->name('client-jobcard.create');
Route::post('client-jobcard', 'ProjectController@store')->name('client-jobcard.store');
Route::get('client-jobcard/edit/{id}', 'ProjectController@edit')->name('client-jobcard.edit');
Route::patch('client-jobcard/{id}', 'ProjectController@update')->name('client-jobcard.update');
```

Database Columns in Migration file:

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 170);
            $table->unsignedInteger('client_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('fundi_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('price')->nullable();
            $table->integer('currency')->nullable();
            $table->string('prefix', 170)->default('JOB');
            $table->string('color')->default('#2E73BA');
            $table->date('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->string('start_time')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('deleted_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace update function with this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name'                  => 'required|string|max:255',
        'description'           => 'required|string|max:255',
        'start_date'            => 'required|date',
        'start_time'            => 'required|string|max:10',
    ]);

    Project::find($id)->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'You have successfully updated your Job Card');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate.